# adding div jquery-free-transform-master

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I want to add functionality to my customizer to add the pictures that have been modified for this purpose I am using a jquery-free-transform-master but I do not know what the problem is. Normal images are added to the popupu class "trans" and id "two" but it's not working. For example, I added a rigid one element to see if libraries are properly attached.

[my project](http://arabcolor.com/customizer/index.html)